# "No Cells Found Error" in Excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am using following code to unMerge and copy the cells. This is the code i am using.

```
Sub unMerge()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    lastRow = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
    lastCol = Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column

    For iCol = 1 To lastCol

        Columns(iCol).unMerge
        Columns(iCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]c"

    Next iCol
End Sub
```

The code works smoothly when there are merged cells in the column however when a column is encountered without merged cells it give the Captioned Error.
What could be the fault in the code.

Comment: well, you have to check first if there are merged cells before unmerging them

Comment: You could try an If-Statement and run the code if a cell is merged?

Answer (score 2):

If no blank cells are found, the SpecialCells method will error out. To avoid this, you may use simple error handling to skip that error

```
On Error Resume Next
Columns(iCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]c"
```

Comment: Although your solution worked fine however, this would work on every error not just the error i mentioned above. Can there be a specific option?

Comment: That's not a big deal. You can reset the errors by using On Error GoTo 0 just after the specialcells line.

Comment: who is that gentleman who downvoted the answer? Maybe he had something better to add here. It would have been really if he had posted it in the comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

If everything else runs smoothly, this is a good way to fix it:

```
Sub unMerge()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim iCol As Long

    lastRow = Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row
    lastCol = Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column

    For iCol = 1 To lastCol
        If Columns(iCol).MergeCells Then Columns(iCol).unMerge
        If RangeContainsCellTypeBlanks(Columns(iCol)) Then
            Columns(iCol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=r[-1]c"
        End If
    Next iCol

End Sub

Public Function RangeContainsCellTypeBlanks(rng As Range) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo RangeContainsCellTypeBlanks_Error    
    If rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count > 0 Then RangeContainsCellTypeBlanks = True

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function    

RangeContainsCellTypeBlanks_Error:    
    RangeContainsCellTypeBlanks = False    
End Function
```

It checks for merged cells and if they are found it performs the unMerge and writes the FormulaR1C1. Here is the Microsoft documentation for the `MergeCells` property: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-mergecells-property-excel

Concerning the SpecialCellsTypeBlanks, there is obviously a known limitation which does not allow to go easily around it, and thus one should use the `On Error Resume Next`, although I am really not a fan of this error catching -https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win003.htm

Thus, at least I am using it in a boolean function, making sure it does not pollute the rest of the code.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, the Merge and UnMerge would not be an issue here, rather, the SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) should be issue here. Because if no blank cells are found, no matter if cells are merged or not, it will error out.

Comment: @sktneer - yup, that's true :)